# Residual analysis without model fitting - how to compare 2 similar curves?

Tags: statistics, curves, regression, descriptive-statistics

I've got 2 curves. One was produced by hand, the other was produced by an algorithm which aims to produce a very similar curve. When testing my algorithm, I'd like to be able to quantify the "similarity" between curves so that when making changes I can judge if I've improved the algorithm or not. For example, if $\{h_i\}$ is the hand crafted data and $\{a_i\}$ and $\{b_i\}$ are curves A and B from 2 versions of my model, I'd like to be able to compare $\{a_i\}$ to $\{h_i\}$ and $\{b_i\}$ to $\{h_i\}$ and then justify picking model version A over version B.

This makes me think of performing residual analysis similar to regression analysis where the hand-crafted curve is $y_{true}$ and the algorithm curve is $y_{fitted}$. In a way, I've already fitted a model via my algorithm and now I just want to analyse the fit. However, I've never done this for data that was not actually fitted via a standard model (e.g. regression) and I am getting some unusual values that I haven't seen before such as a very negative $R^2$. Are there any methods to compare 2 curves that are not related by a model?

Another idea that might or might not work is to regress the model curve against the hand-crafted curve and then analyse the regression. Would this make sense?

Comment: I would have thought negative $R^2$ should mean that your curve is a worse fit than drawing a horizontal line through the mean of the data. I doubt things are as bad as that.

Comment: @Henry The input is from several data sources and it falls back (e.g. if data available from source1 else from source 2 else from source 3 etc). I tried decomposing the curve per data source and for some data sources there are only a few points - this is when I get the very negative R2. I guess it makes sense then.